# How to close the desktop application running in background when called from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-application, taskmanager, desktop-bridge

I am working on UWP app where in I have added Fulltrust permissions to my app in order to get access to the desktop application using APpServiceConncetion. But whenever I call FullTrustProcessLauncher it creates a new instance of my desktop application under my UWP app in task manager and it looks like it consumes CPU memory for each desktop app.
How do I close/keep only one  instance of desktop app when I call it from UWP?

Also How can I kill desktop application from task manager/ background when I no more require this code using c# in UWP

Answer (score 1):

You are in full control of the lifetime of your desktop application process, assuming you own the code. So your process can shut itself down whenever it is no longer needed. A common good practice is to shutdown when the appservice connection gets closed (i.e. the UWP app goes away and the ServiceClosed event fires).

There is some details on this in this post (under "Handling Process Exit Scenarios - Scenario 2"):
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Comment: Thanks, I already have a ServiceClosed event in my desktop application. But I noticed that it was not fired even if I no longer communicate with desktop application. And desktop app instance is still present in task manager. Every time when I call FullTrustProcessLauncher to run desktop application based on my requirement additional instance of desktop app is created. For e.g., If I call FullTrustProcessLauncher three times to access a desktop app, three instances are created under my UWP app in task Manager.

Comment: Can you share a repro project and clarify the steps? The ServiceClosed event should fire when the UWP app terminates. Alternatively, you could also just reuse the running desktop app process by implementing a Singleton pattern for it.